# When i export files from blender there are some unknown shapes blocking my models

Tags: modeling, export

I'm a new Blender user, I use Daz to Blender bridge to pose Daz model in Blender, then I export its .obj to clip studio paint, but when I import it to clip studio paint, there are some unknown shapes blocking my whole models.

I don’t know where it’s come from and how to get rid of it. I tried .fbx instead and doesn’t change anything. I tried import that .obj file that I just exported, back to blender and there are still those unknown shapes blocking my models.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you have any hidden objects in your file?  It looks like we'll probably need to see some screenshots in Blender in order to see what's going on.  If desired, you may additionally [include your .blend file](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/344/5705).  As it is we can''t really tell which parts of your screenshot are unwanted.

Comment: I tried to upload more screenshot, hope it could help

Comment: The model at first then i export it as obj then open it again in blender and those shapes appear

Answer (score 2):

Can you try export with that settings
[image]